# how to store images gotten from requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I basically used requests and now I have links to webpages which have images on them. I want to extract just the images and make a file where I store them for later viewing. How would I do so?

```
import requests
import string
import random


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


for i in range(50):
    link = id_generator()
    print("https://prnt.sc/" + link)
    r = requests.get("https://prnt.sc/" + link)
```

Comment: Have you searched for that and what did you get? It's a very common problem and likely already answered somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.get("https://i.imgur.com/ExdKOOz.png")

file = open("sample_image.png", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Really, a context manager should be used when handling files, such as `with open(...) ...`.

Comment: Thats a good point, but was giving him something to work with as this is a very easy Googlable answer..

Comment: Understood. Perhaps better to teach the proper method, rather than something to work with?  :-)

Comment: what do the last 3 lines of the code do?